# How can I turn brightness to transparency in grayscale image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, grayscale

I would like to turn a grayscale image into a transparent image where:

- `#000000` (black) → turns into → `#000000` (black) 0% transparency
- `#FFFFFF` (white) → turns into → `#000000` (black) 100% transparency

Example image of a grayscale gradient (on the left) and desired result (on the right).

How can I do this in Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: Load any of the channels as alpha. Hide your layer make new layer fill with black.done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Go to the *Channels* panel.
- Hold <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> and left-click the *Gray* channel to make a selection.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to inverse the selection.
- Go to the *Layers* panel.
- Click the *Create a new layer* button.
- Make sure the foreground color is black.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to fill the selection with black.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to deselect.
- Delete the *Background* layer.

[image]